# sql server print a register starting your initial date until your final date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, intervals

I have a lot of registers in my Database with startdate and enddate. I need to print the interval between these dates, month per month. Example:

```
StartDate      EndDate
2015-01-01     2015-12-01
```

I need to print like

```
2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
2015-04-01
```

until 2015-12-01 for which one registers

Comment: Are you able to show what you have tried, i.e. in a form of a query?

Comment: What do you mean by register and print?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE, @endDate DATE
SELECT @startDate = '2015-01-01', @endDate = '2015-12-01' 
;WITH Calender AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,CalanderDate) FROM Calender
    WHERE DATEADD(month,1,CalanderDate) <= @endDate
)
SELECT * FROM Calender ORDER BY CalanderDate
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4567)

Comment: I need to relation with a mean, the principal table that´s contains the data

Comment: I need to relation with a mean, the principal table that´s contains the data i.e StartData, Description, EndData and for wich one register I need to print the interval. example i have  start date= 2015-01-01, description test1, enddate=2015-12-01....second register startdate=2015-03-05, description=test2, enddate=2015-12-05. the expected result   register 1  2015-01-01, test1,  
line below 2015-02-01, test1  
line below 2015-03-01, test1

Answer (score 0):

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 0 AS months
UNION ALL 
SELECT  months + 1
FROM CTE, TESTE t1
WHERE months < datediff(month,t1.dateid,t1.enddate)and t1.code=t1.code)
SELECT  distinct t2.code, DATEADD(MONTH,months,t2.dateid), t2.Dscription, t2.Credit, t2.enddate
FROM CTE, TESTE t2  where t2.code=t2.code and DATEADD(MONTH,months,t2.dateid)<=t2.enddate but I need to change to a normal select because crystal reports desn´t accept cte